2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Bioacoustics's Moderator election #5 has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:


Thanks to everyone for their help (past, present, and future!)
